# Unix maximum number of dirs in a dir

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10. Also I am using `ext4` filesystem.

Is there is an upper limit on the no. of dirs you can create in a unix dir without affecting performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ext2` (or `ext3` filesystems that were created before the `dir_index` option became the default), then the limit would be somewhere under 10,000 entries.

But if your filesystem is `ext3` or `ext4` and was created with `dir_index`, then the limit would be around 64k files per directory. (Check with `tune2fs -l /dev/block_device` to see if `dir_index` was enabled.)

Keep in mind that the `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4`, and probably other filesystems also have an upper limit on the number of files that can exist on the filesystem: the inode limit. (Check with `tune2fs -l /dev/block_device`. Configure with `mkfs.ext*` option `-N`.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the file system you are using. By default Ubuntu 10.10 uses "ext4" filesystem, which has a limit 64,000 (see [Wikipedia article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)

Comment: 64k is the max. but at what point will accessing data from this directory structure cause slow-down in access times?